# Cannot remove symbolic link to passwd

Tags: symbolic-link

Was just trying to learn and test on creation of symbolic link and relative symbolic link.
I did the following command:

1. `ln -P /etc/passwd linkPassword`
2. `ln -r -s /etc/passwd RlinkPassword`

Both worked and the two link files are on my /root/Desktop/.

Now, I tried to delete them using unlink or rm but all permission denied even if using sudo.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your commands, and had no issue deleting the link files using rm.

however, if you still have permission issue, try the below command

`lsattr linkPassword`

and see if it has letter `i` in it (it means immutable) in the output. If you see `i`, you have to remove this attribute first before you can delete those files.

```
chattr -i linkPassword
rm -rf linkPassword
```

Comment: Hi FangQ, 
thanks for your suggestion but I can't seems to get that command running also.



<br><br>[root@localhost Desktop]# lsattr linkPassword
lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on linkPassword

<br />[root@localhost Desktop]# chattr -i linkPassword
chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags on linkPassword

Comment: then, you must have somehow removed the r/w permission. just do `chmod +rwx linkPassword` and then you can delete the file.